# Possible to filter an ActiveRecord query based on multiple "belongs_to" relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

I want to get all the posts that have a relation to `user` AND `category`. Is any similar possible:

```
user.category.posts
```

Or do I need to do:

```
user.posts.where(category_id: category.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `1-M relationship` between `User` and `Post`. 
In User model association should be `has_many :posts` (note plural)and not `has_many :post`(singular).

Update your model `User` as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts  ## Plural posts
end
```

To answer below question:

> get all the posts that have a relation to user AND category

Assuming that you have local variables `user` and `category` as an instance of `User` model and `Category` model respectively.

For example:

```
user = User.find(1); ## Get user with id 1
category = Category.find(1); ## Get category with id 1
user.posts.where(category_id: category.id) ## would get you what you need.
```

Also, `user.category.posts` will not work as `User` and `Category` models are not associated.

Comment: OK, so my sought-after syntax is not possible. Thanks for pointing out the type.

Comment: To use `user.category.posts` syntax, you would have to create an association between User and Category, else its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
user.posts.where(category_id: category.id)
```

Comment: How's that different from the last line in my question?

Comment: In user.category.posts, category model doesnot contain the user id and also there is no relation between user model and category model

Answer (score 0):

Change your association like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :category
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :post
 belongs_to :category or has_one :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :user or belongs_to :user
 has_many :posts
end
```

in users table add column `category_id`,or add column `user_id` in categories,because you don't have relation between those two tables.if you don't have relation you can't use association API's.then you have to use manual API to fetch the data.like how you have mentioned your question.